# Как соединить две части кода для вывода всех категорий в Magento?

Tags: php, magento

Столкнулся с проблемой вывода всех категорий и суб-категорий из одной главной категории ID3. К сожалению не нашёл решения, но нашёл кусок кода, который выводит все категории, но не могу его структурировать, чтобы получилось вертикальное меню. Или подскажите, пожалуйста, где я могу найти информацию по изучению выражений для magento? Первый кусок выводит только первоначальный список категорий, по структуре полностью рабочий.

```html
<?php
$categoryId = 3;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$_categories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
?>
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav block-layered-nav--no-filters">
    <div class="block-content toggle-content open">
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
            <dt><?php echo $this->__('Каталог') ?></dt>
            <dd>
                <ol>
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                    <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>>
                            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Вторая часть все выводит категории, но не знаю как оформить по аналогии с моей, или совместить их.

```html
<?php
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4);
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();

foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
{
  $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
  if($_category->getIsActive()) {
    echo '<ul><a href="'.$_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_category->getName().'" category">'.$_category->getName().'</a>';
    $sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
    $sub_subcats = $sub_cat->getChildren();
    foreach(explode(',',$sub_subcats) as $sub_subCatid)
    {
          $_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
          if($_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
              echo '<li class="sub_cat"><a href="'.$_sub_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_sub_category->getName().'" category">'.$_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';
              $sub_sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
              $sub_sub_subcats = $sub_sub_cat->getChildren();
              foreach(explode(',',$sub_sub_subcats) as $sub_sub_subCatid)
              {
                $_sub_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_sub_subCatid);
                if($_sub_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
                    echo '<li class="sub_cat"><a href="'.$_sub_sub_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_sub_sub_category->getName().'" category">'.$_sub_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';
                }
              }
           }
     }
     echo '</ul>';
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения всех категорий и подкатегорий желательно использовать рекурсивный подхом в методе, то есть методт что будет вызывать сам себя, [вот](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/14/magento-generate-category-tree-recursively/) хороший пример, можешь взять его за основу.

Comment: У меня есть для меню рекурсивный, но на него не получается грамотно навесить меню с аккордеоном, почему-то открывается и закрывается по три раза при нажатии на вкладку. Здесь пробовал по разному обёртывать в аккордеон, но так и не понял как грамотно. [код](https://jsfiddle.net/Sylon/vnuyccch/1/)

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, как его применить относительно одной категории ID 3, чтобы вывести все её категории и их детей?

Comment: В примере из прошлого коммента в самом начале передается ид рутовой категории, где можно передать любой ид категории с которой начинать.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, на коде, я пробовал вариации, меню исчезает. Просто если бы я владел в полной мере php, то вопрос бы не пришлось задавать, а частей кода в инете много.

Comment: Так то да, но если нет знаний php + хоть немного Magento то простыми примерами не объяснить, нужно знать что должно быть в конце, так сказать саму концепцию задания. А так в коде все просто вот - http://joxi.ru/Vm6vqyqfxvN1Gm

Comment: Просто вывести все вложения категории ID3. Пробовал подставить её номер, но всё пропадало. Пробовал первую строку убирать, а во второй номер ID 3 ставить.